# How to detect if a function call is from ServerComp or ClientComp in Next 13 app dir?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I want to know weather a function can know weather it is being called from a `server` component or a `client` component.

The reason being is that I have to perform the same task but the imports are different.
eg, reading the cookie values I have 2 different imports depending from where is is called from,

- Server comp, import   `cookies` from next/headers
- Client comp, import  `getCookie` from cookies-next

The same is for importing `supabase` client, it is different for `server` and `client`

tried checking `typeof window` to see if its a client or server comp.
but that did not work well

Answer (score 0):

In my code I check `window` and it works:

```
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const key = "bunkering_table";
    addTableToLocSto(key, table);
  }
```

It is located inside the component's function `setTable(table: CTable)`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTable(new CTable(props));
    console.log(new CTable(props));
  }, []);
```